# powershell script to delete x days old file automatically. pass two parameters in it one for path of file and other one for no. of days to keep files

Tags: windows, powershell, parameter-passing, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to write a PowerShell script for deleting a folder automatically using notepad and I also want to add 2 parameters to this script. Whenever I run this script it asks for path and no. of days old file.

```
Param1 - location of the folder
Param2 - no. Of days to keep

$param1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'location of the folder'
$param2 = Read-Host -Prompt 'no. of days to keep'
Get-ChildItem $param1 -recurse  | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($param2)} | 
    Remove-Item
```

---

Is there any solution to pass parameters in the PowerShell script? In my code param1 is taking input but param2 is not taking any input.

Comment: The 2 prompts come up for the arguments to be entered when I run it. How are you calling on the script?

Comment: yes, 2 prompts come up for the arguments but the value of param2 is not updating anything. either it's 15 days or 1000 days this code always deletes files, I want to set the no. of days. when I tried to print this code line by line using write-host then it is printing only till first vertical bar and updating param1 but not param2.

Comment: Thanks, Lieven Keersmaekers for editing this script. Only indentation error was there. thanks for resolving this.

Answer (score 2):

First - please name your parameters properly - it's easier to read. :)

Second - if you want older than x - you have to `.AddDays(-$days)`.

So it might look like this:

```
$path = Read-Host -Prompt 'location of the folder'
$days = Read-Host -Prompt 'no. of days to keep'
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse  | 
    #Mind the -$days (so we are looking for older than (today - X days)
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days) } | 
    Remove-Item #-WhatIf #for testing
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept is the same as in [Grzegorz's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68002972/15339544), I just added some input validation and error handling.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$param1Block = {
    try
    {
        [validatescript({Test-Path $_})]$z = Read-Host -Prompt 'location of the folder'
        $z
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning 'Invalid Path, try again.'
        & $param1Block
    }
}

$param2Block = {
    try
    {
        [int](Read-Host -Prompt 'no. of days to keep')
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning 'Only integers accepted, try again.'
        & $param2Block
    }
}

$param1 = & $param1Block
$param2 = & $param2Block

if([math]::Sign($param2) -ne -1)
{
    $param2 = -$param2
}

Get-ChildItem $param1 -Recurse |
Where-Object -Property LastWriteTime -LT ([datetime]::Now).AddDays($param2) |
Remove-Item
```